What rule or standard is used to assign a SOT number to a chip housing?
I studied the datasheets of some Philips chips and found that they housing have several designations. In particular, many packages are signed like DBS9P (as I understand it, this is a DIL Bent SIL family of packages), and there is a specific name of the package, for example SOT523-1.
However, the SOT523 package is also a package for small SMD component. Why are they called the same?
There are other examples that are completely confusing, such as the LH7A400 from NXP. The datasheet says that this chip has a BGA package: 256-ball BGA or 256-ball LFBGA Package, but if you scroll down to the drawing of the package itself, it also says Package outline SOT1020-1 (LFBGA256).
What actually is this SOT number? It is clearly not an abbreviation for small outline transistor... Or?

Are you getting overly concerned that the T (that stands for transistor) is also part of the SOT package name for devices that consist of multiple transistors i.e. chips?

@Andyaka Well, technically there are also diodes available in SOT23 or SOT323 packages. But I agree, it's not really important that "T" stands for transistor, package names are a mess anyway.

@Andyaka I am concerned that different cases have the same names (in my question there is such an example - sot523, these are completely different cases, read more carefully). Therefore, I want to know if there is some standard regulating the assignment of this number.

If you just search NXP for SOT: https://www.nxp.com/packages/search?q=SOT I think it's clear that they just use SOT as a package version prefix. Who knows if it stands for anything.

@nanash1 but it's not just NXP that does this, I also gave an example from Philips, which has exactly the same name as a common transistor package

@Никитос NXP is Philips.

Okay, so I understand that it was Philips specifically who chose this abbreviation?

SOT523-1 is not the same as SOT523 @Никитос

Consider: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/package-information/SOT323.pdf
Take the relevant headline items one by one:

"Package type industry code: SC-70": there is some wider industry agreement on this terminology.
"JEITA package outline code: SC-70": JEITA is a Japanese electronics standards association; this is the code for a standard, and NXP has adopted it.
"Manufacturer package code: SOT323": NXP is the manufacturer. They are telling us they have named it thusly.  So, JEITA's SC-70 is used by NXP, which they have named SOT323.
Page 2, the drawing has a title block including their "outline version", and applicable references.  IEC is the EU standards association; JEDEC, a US/western electronics standards association.  It seems JEDEC either does not have this (or a similar enough) package on file, or NXP didn't see fit to reference it here for whatever reason.

Compare to their SOT-23, which gives a JEDEC reference TO-236AB (but no others).
Other manufacturers have their own designations, for example onsemi SOT-23 is called a "CASE 318", or TI DBZ (among other variants).  Some exceptions (to the reference drawings) or variations are evident in the notes.  TI's packages and variants can be looked up here.
As SOT1020-1 carries no references, it seems it is not, or at least directly, derived from an industry standards organization (or, again, that they didn't see fit to locate and cite such).  Other more general standards may have been used to create the package, or exist as de facto standards between manufacturers and fabs (for example, many use some variant of [alphabet-soup-]BGAxxx as a common designation for packages like this).
Note that the availability and use of standards, reflects the state of the industry that uses them.  Right now, the majority of manufacturers are "fabless", i.e. they don't own the machinery, process, IP, workforce, etc. to physically craft silicon devices, but rather contract out to a service (GlobalFoundries, TSMC, Samsung, ST, TI, etc.).  Those services in turn have options for packaging: from standard offerings, to whatever the client demands (within reason) -- but costs are least, and products the most reliable, in common well-tested formats, so it's no accident that packages become standardized in an ad-hoc manner, without the need for industry-wide agreement.

I understand, thanks for the detailed answer.
